# UICollectionView + NSFetchedResultsController + performBatchUpdates

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uicollectionview

I have been testing the proposed solution [here](https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionView-NSFetchedResultsController) for updating a `UICollectionView` from a `NSFetcherResultsController`. But I having some issues.

My `UICollectionView` shows a hierachy (sorted by name) of folders and documents. Tapping on a document open it and tapping on a folder push a new controller with a `UICollectionView` (drill down).

The user can copy/cut/paste documents and folders.

Example of the issue:

```
Root
|
---"B"
    |---"A"
```

If I copy "A" form "B" to Root, "A" is inserted in Root, and "B" is updated (elmentsCount--). The problem is that "B" is getting the animation for inserting, and "A" is getting the animation for update.

I have put two log messages inside the block that I am using for performing the batch update:

```
case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
    NSLog(@"INSERTING at pos : %d", ((NSIndexPath *)obj).item);
    [self.libraryCollectionBrowser insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
    break;
 case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
    NSLog(@"UPDATING at pos : %d", ((NSIndexPath *)obj).item);
    [self.libraryCollectionBrowser reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[obj]];
    break;
```

The log is:

```
INSERTING at pos : 0
UPDATING at pos : 0
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Could you share with us your `controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` method ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response Daniel, I was using the code provided in this link: https://github.com/AshFurrow/UICollectionView-NSFetchedResultsController